# Mac can import cv2 by vscode

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

I installed conda and vscode on my mac, then installed jupyter notebook, opencv, py-opencv etc.

My python version is 3.9, then I changed the 3.9 to 3.7 in case to install opencv and py-opencv.

Now, I can run import cv2 using jupyter(name.ipynb), but can not import formally python(name.py)

I checked the version on the terminal, the python version is 3.9,  The conda environment is 3.7. I think that this is the problem.

but I do not have ideas to solve it.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: You could try installing opencv using pip3 to see if opencv can be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Hello did you installed all packages inside conda environment using pip3?

Comment: I installed packages by anaconda.

Comment: $ conda activate <env-name>, $ pip3 install jupyterlab, $ pip3 install python-opencv

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The program can import cv2 by pycharm, so the vscode is very strange for my environment.